# Give all managers a 10 percent raise unless the salary becomes greater than $100,000; in such cases, give only a 3 percent raise

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have the following database scheema.

```
employee (employee-name, street, city)
    works (employee-name, company-name, salary)
    company (company-name, city)
    manages (employee-name, manager-name)
```

I need to find Give all managers of First Bank Corporation a 10 percent raise unless the salary becomes greater than $100,000; in such cases, give only a 3 percent raise.

I have written the following query to the above question.

```
UPDATE works w, manages m
SET w.salary += (salary * 0.10)
WHERE w.employee-name = m.manager-name
AND w.company-name = ‘First Bank Corporation’
```

But as can be seen from the query i am not checking the case when the salary is greater than $100000. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, they need a 10% raise if AFTER the raise they do not cross 100K, in that case use this query;

```
UPDATE works w, manages m
SET w.salary += salary * case when salary+salary*0.10 > 1000000 then 0.03 else 0.10 end
WHERE w.employee-name = m.manager-name
AND w.company-name = ‘First Bank Corporation’
```

If the case is that they need a 10% raise if they are CURRENTLY beneath 100K use the following;

```
UPDATE works w, manages m
SET w.salary += salary * case when salary > 1000000 then 0.03 else 0.10 end
WHERE w.employee-name = m.manager-name
AND w.company-name = ‘First Bank Corporation’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET w.salary *= case when salary > 1000000 then 1.03 else 1.10 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a case statement

```
UPDATE works w, manages m
SET w.salary = (CASE
WHEN (w.salary * 0.10) < 100000 THEN w.salary + (salary * 0.10)
ELSE w.salary + (salary * 0.03)
END CASE)
WHERE w.employee-name = m.manager-name
AND w.company-name = ‘First Bank Corporation’
```